# Suppress the text "Figure X about here" in the endfloat package

Tags: floats, endfloat

The endfloat package is very useful to programmatically move all floats to the end of a manuscript without manually editing each floating environment.  However, it introduces a placeholder tag with the text "Figure X about here".  For my current use case, I would prefer it simply move the figures to the end silently, and not print this placeholder text.

I can suppress the figure/table table-of-contents it creates by re-defining the commands:

```
\usepackage{endfloat} % Floats at end
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{} % but suppress these lists
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{} % suppress these lists
```

But not sure what to do to remove the "[Figure X about here]" text.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `nomarkers` option:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
```

As a side note, instead of redefining `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, you can suppress them using the package options `nofiglist`, `notablist`

```
\usepackage[notablist,nofiglist]{endfloat}
```

or equivalently, [nolists]